# Chrome S3 Cloudfront: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header on initial and load request

Tags: php, google-chrome, amazon-s3, cors, amazon-cloudfront

I have a webpage uses angular js to load some image file from S3 through the CloudFront CDN.

In Chrome I will open an Incognito window as well as the console. they shows some error message 
Failed to load

**http://cloudfront.net/image.png No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'yyy' is therefore not allowed access.**

but no issues in the firebox all images are load. but i face only issues in the chrome

I have checked, changed, and re-checked the settings on S3 and Cloudfront. In S3 my CORS configuration looks like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedOrigin>http://*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedOrigin>https://*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
    <AllowedHeader>Authorization</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

And also try my .htaccess file like

```
<ifModule mod_headers.c>
    Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
    Header add Access-Control-Allow-Headers "origin, x-requested-with, content-type"
    Header add Access-Control-Allow-Methods "PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS"
</IfModule>
```

but error shows in the chrome browsers, please any body help to fix the problem

Comment: Have you read this : http://blog.celingest.com/en/2014/10/02/tutorial-using-cors-with-cloudfront-and-s3/

Comment: Or this: https://serverfault.com/q/856904/153161. S3 does not send `Vary: Origin` in the response, when there is no `Origin:` in the first request.

Answer (score 0):

Add a Cloudfront "Edge-To-Origin" Origin header to force CORS response headers on every request (xhr or non-xhr):

Origin ---> http://sub.domain.com